# opencart - multi vendor 404 Not Found in fresh installation

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have done fresh installation of openkart multivendor.Once I configure the all installation file, Its successfully connected to 000webhost database and created tables there.

But when its shows the page where from where we need to go to either to shop or to admin page, If I click on either of the thing its redirected back to /insall/index.php page and another afresh configuration starts.

So I thought it might be happening because I haven't deleted install directory from public_html folder. So, I removed the /install directory from there,
Now when I refresh my site then its showing 404 NOt found error.

Even if I redirecting the site to /admin/index.php, its taking /install/index.php.

I gone through many forum but haven't find solution for this.
Please help me for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was problem from webhost side. it was making config.php folder instead of file and that is the reason it was not working